# Android Custom Array adapter issue

Tags: android

I am new in android.I have an app in android in which I return some data from a .Net WebService (names and id's) after return this data i use an adapter to set all those names in a list view. I have checked with debugger that ARRAY LIST is getting data from WEB SERVICE, but LISTVIEW in android SDK doesn't show any result .

My Adapters code is:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyValues>{
Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
List data = null;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder view;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            // Get a new instance of the row layout view
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multirow, null);

            // Hold the view objects in an object, that way the don't need to be "re-  finded"
            view = new ViewHolder();
            view.name= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            view.address= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

            rowView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        /** Set data to your Views. */
        MyValues item =(MyValues) data.get(position); //List.get(position);
        view.name.setText(item.getName());
        view.address.setText(item.getAddress());

        return rowView;
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView address;
    }


}
```

My Values class code is:

```
public class MyValues {
private String name;
private String address;

public MyValues(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address= address;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
}
```

My Activity class code is:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;


import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class SimpleListViewActivity extends Activity {

private static String SOAP_ACTION_D = "http://tempuri.org/GetSalesMen";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 private static String METHOD_NAME_D = "GetSalesMen";
private static String URL_D = "http://apollon.dnet.gr/webservice/Service1.asmx";
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

SoapObject table = null;                
SoapObject tableRow = null;     
SoapObject responseBody = null;    

 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_D);        

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;

try {
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_D);

    List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +   org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("administrator:MyPassword".getBytes())));

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_D, envelope, headerList);

    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    int intPropertyCount = result.getPropertyCount();
    {
        responseBody = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        responseBody = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(1);

        table = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(0);
        ArrayList<MyValues> list = new ArrayList<MyValues>();
        SoapObject responseChild = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
        int lengthOfResponseChild = responseChild.getPropertyCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfResponseChild; j++){
            tableRow  = (SoapObject) table.getProperty(j);
            list.add(new MyValues(tableRow.getProperty(2).toString(),      tableRow.getProperty(1).toString()));

        }  
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this,R.id.mainListView, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 }

    public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }

  }

}
```

Can someone help me.Thanks

Comment: define `not working properly`

Comment: You should edit your question, and give a little detail about what is 'not working properly'. Nobody is going to guess what the problem could be, post some logcat output, give a detailed description what goes wrong, and what you would expect to happen instead.

Comment: can you add the layouts for R.layout.main and R.layout.multirow .. it's possible that your problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Implement `getCount` method at your adapter class:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyValues>{
   //...Your current codes here
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       if(data == null) {
          return 0;
       } else { 
          return data.size();
       }
   }
}
```

BTW `StableArrayAdapter` is not being used in your code. (I haven't seen any references to that here at your shared code.) Remove it from here if it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything on the UI thread. Look for AsyncTask or Threads. That may result in a not responding window where you can still test it if you press wait and but it's not correct, use it only for test before you write an AsyncTask or Thread.

StableArrayAdapter is not used anywhere is that right; Better clean your code!

Can you log or debug the properties of `list` has any data after the parse;

The mentioned code of MyArrayAdapter seems fine.